# Not able to show JSP from Jersey : MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html

Tags: java, jsp, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am getting following error and my JSP is not being loaded.

```
[info] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-06-07 13:04:16 INFO  ReportController:242 - welcome page load called
Jun 07, 2016 1:04:16 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, 
type=class org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable, 
genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable.
```

But all my **JSON url is working fine**.

Following are my code blocks.

```
@Path("/reports")
public class ReportController extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @POST
    @Path("/submitReport")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public  ReportDTO submitReportCall (ReportDTO submitReportRequest) {
         //.....
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public Viewable index(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute("obj", new String("IT Works"));
        LOGGER.info("welcome page load called");
        return new Viewable("/WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp", null);
    }
}
```

web.xml is as follows.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mytool.rest.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
              <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
              <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
          </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

====**EDIT**====

**Modified web.xml with filter**

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>jersey-serlvet</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.aol.compoundtool.rest.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature, org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
              <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
          </init-param>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey-serlvet</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/aol/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: You can only use init-params once I think. If you want to use multiple values for a single param name, separate them with a comma or semicolon or new line. I think the problem is the JspMvcFeature is not being registered

Comment: Also with your viewable, you should not use the `WEB-INF/jsp` in the path, its already configured in the web.xml. I think you should just use `main`. Maybe `main.jsp`, but I think `main` should be enough.

Comment: I also tried that but no success. Now looking for how to declare multiple param value

Comment: no success with comma by separating provider.classnames. :(

Comment: Can you update your post with the new configuration?

Comment: You'll need to register your servletcontainer as servlet filter instead of servlets in the web.xml. More here https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html#d0e15418

Comment: When I am using filter then neither JSON is working nor JSP. Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was having this same issue on Jersey 2.22.2. This is using Jetty 9ish

in my case i was missing

```
<dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.ext" name="jersey-mvc-jsp" rev="2.22.2"/>
```

for that specific error message. 
Ivy wasn't getting other required dependencies either.

check https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/2.22.2/modules-and-dependencies.html#modules
sub your version of jersey in the url for the right version of docs

my filter def

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>jersey-servlet</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                         com.foo.services.mobile.resource,
                         com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature,
                    org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature
                </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jersey-servlet</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

to support Multipart upload and JSP MVC  these are my dependencies. 
[image]
but get all of what is listed under compile for what ever features you are using. and test if you want to test.